# arm-gcc mktime binary size

Tags: gcc, arm, stm32, newlib

I need to perform simple arithmetic on `struct tm` from `time.h`. I need to add or subtract seconds or minutes, and be able to normalize the structure. Normally, I'd use `mktime(3)` which performs this normalization as a side effect:

```c
struct tm t = {.tm_hour=0, .tm_min=59, .tm_sec=40};
t.tm_sec += 30;
mktime(&t);
// t.tm_hour is now  1
// t.tm_min  is now  0
// t.tm_sec  is now 10
```

I'm doing this on an STM32 with 32 kB of flash, and binary gets very big. `mktime(3)` and the other stuff it pulls in take up 16 kB of flash--half the available space.

Is there a function in newlib that is specifically responsible for `struct tm` normalization? I realize that linking to a private function like that would make the code less portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `validate_structure()` function in `newlib/libc/time/mktime.c` which does a part of the job, normalizes month, day-of-month, hour, min, sec, but leaves day-of-week and day-of-year alone.

It's declared `static`, so you can't simply call it, but you can copy the function from the sources. (There might be licensing issues though). Or you can just reimplement it, it's quite straightforward.

The `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` is calculated later in `mktime()`, so you'd need the whole mess including the timezone stuff in order to have these two normalized.

The bulk of that 16kB code is related to a call to `siscanf()`, a variant of `sscanf()` without floating point support, which is (I believe) used to parse timezone and DST information in environment variables.

You can cut lots of unnecessary code by using **`--specs=nano.specs`** when linking, which would switch to simplified `printf`/`scanf` code, saving about 10kB of code in your case.

Comment: This is an embedded system that computes everything in UTC, and happens not to care about `tm_wday` and `tm_yday`, so `validate_structure` is perfect for what I need. But your other suggestion, `-specs=nano.specs`, is even more appealing, at least until I run out of flash. It saves an even 8,000 bytes in the `.elf`, giving me enough headroom at least for now. Thank you!